WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance
I am using a software for web scraping. When I try to use the Crawler, I get the following error. Could you please help me?

WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance. Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 60484 Only local connections are allowed. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. ChromeDriver was started successfully. Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary Build info: version: '4.2.0', revision: '86eb611648' System info: host: 'DESKTOP-O4IBNLU', ip: '192.168.0.101', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '20' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--blink-settings=imagesEnab..., --js-flags="--max_old_space..., --remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: [Q3IyNAMAAAAcBQAAEqwECqYCMII..., Q3IyNAMAAAAeBQAAEqwECqYCMII...]}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--blink-settings=imagesEnab..., --js-flags="--max_old_space..., --remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: [Q3IyNAMAAAAcBQAAEqwECqYCMII..., Q3IyNAMAAAAeBQAAEqwECqYCMII...]}}}]         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:566)         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:163)         at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:93)         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)         at Main.main(Main.java:46)**

There was a compatibility problem with the browser (Google Chrome: 130.0.6723.58). With a ChromeDriver of version 114.0.5735.90, my Google Chrome version 130.0.6723.58 was incompatible. So, I uninstalled this browser to then install a Google Chrome browser of version 114.0.5735.91. The problem still persists.
Pom.xml:
4.0.0

<groupId>org.webdb</groupId>
<artifactId>crawler</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <main.class>Main</main.class>

    <build.title>crawler</build.title>
    <version.prefix>v</version.prefix>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${build.jar.name}</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    ${main.class}
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.moandjiezana.toml</groupId>
        <artifactId>toml4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.tongfei</groupId>
        <artifactId>progressbar</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Main Method:
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

import me.tongfei.progressbar.ProgressBar;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy;
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated;

public class Main {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
    private static String searchXPathName = "Input.PostalCode";

    private static WebDBConfig webDBConfig;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final WebDBConfig config = new WebDBConfig(getConfigSource(args));
        webDBConfig = config;

        var outWriter = createFileOut(config.outputFile);
        var xpaths = parseXpathFile(config.xPathsFile);
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); 
        var options = new ChromeOptions()
                .addArguments("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false", "--js-flags=\"--max_old_space_size=500\"")
                .addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*")
                .addExtensions(new File(config.addonsPath.stripTrailing() + "/adblock.crx"),
                        new File(config.addonsPath.stripTrailing() + "/no_cookies.crx"));

        // This will throw a lot of warnings, but it also does so without options and
        // is 1 to 1 what the wiki says should be done. I guess the defaults are just
        // bad?
        // It also disregards any loglevel set, so this cant even be silenced :)
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Parse search terms and search them
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(config.searchTermPath))) {
            var searchTerms = new ArrayList<String>();
            String currentSearchTerm = null;
            while ((currentSearchTerm = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                searchTerms.add(currentSearchTerm);
            }
            for (String searchTerm : ProgressBar.wrap(searchTerms, "Crawling")) {
                doSearch(driver, xpaths, searchTerm, config.url, outWriter, config.pressEnter);
            }
            outWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error reading search terms: {}", e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        driver.quit();
        logger.info("Finished crawling");
    }

    private static File getConfigSource(String[] args) {
        final File defaultSource = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".webdb", "components.toml").toFile();

        // if there are no arguments given, don't bother and return default
        if (args.length == 0) {
            return defaultSource;
        }

        // arguments passed with a keyword are generally considered non-positional, so
        // just try to find the config
        // argument in all arguments regardless of index
        File givenSource = null;
        for (String arg : args) {
            if (!arg.startsWith("--config=")) {
                continue;
            }

            // if the correct keyword is found, cut it from the argument and read the
            // remaining string
            givenSource = Paths.get(arg.replaceFirst("^--config=", "")).toFile();
        }

        return Objects.requireNonNullElse(givenSource, defaultSource);
    }

    private static Map<String, String> parseXpathFile(String path) {
        Map<String, String> inputmap = new HashMap<>();
        try (BufferedReader xpFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            String currentXP = null;
            while ((currentXP = xpFile.readLine()) != null) {
                var split = currentXP.split("=", 2);
                if (split.length == 2)
                    inputmap.put(split[0], split[1]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to read xpath file: {}", e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return inputmap;
    }

    /*
     * creates the results-file
     */
    private static FileWriter createFileOut(String path) {
        FileWriter f = null;
        try {
            File resultFile = new File(path);
            if (!resultFile.createNewFile()) {
                Files.delete(resultFile.toPath());
                Files.createFile(resultFile.toPath());
            }
            f = new FileWriter(resultFile, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error writing output file: {}", e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return f;
    }

    private static void doSearch(ChromeDriver driver, Map<String, String> inputmap, String currentSearchTerm,
            String url, FileWriter fw, Boolean pressEnter) {

        logger.info("Crawling: {} ", currentSearchTerm);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            driver.get(url);

            // Input search term
            try {
                wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(inputmap.get(searchXPathName)))).click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(inputmap.get(searchXPathName))).clear();
                wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(inputmap.get(searchXPathName))))
                        .sendKeys(pressEnter ? currentSearchTerm + Keys.ENTER : currentSearchTerm);// Enter can break some sites(wikipedia) but without this immonet does not work
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error entering the search term: {}", e.getMessage());
                continue;
            }

            // Click search button
            try {
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(inputmap.get("Button.Find")))).click();
                // TODO: Eigentlich müsste man hier auch warten, bis die seite refreshed ist.
                iterateResults(driver, new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(2)), inputmap, fw);
                return;
            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                logger.error("Stale reference in start page: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                logger.error("Timeout on the start page click: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error clicking on the search button: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        // We were unable to start the search
    }

    /*
     * iteratively crawles the result urls for one search_term by trying to click
     * the NextButton
     */
    private static void iterateResults(ChromeDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait, Map<String, String> inputmap,
            FileWriter fw) {
        List<WebElement> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                for (WebElement elem : driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"))) {
                    driver.switchTo().frame(elem);
                }
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                results = wait.until(presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(inputmap.get("Item.Result"))));
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception t) {
                    //
                }
            }
        }
        if (results.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            try {
                for (WebElement element : results) {
                    String currentImmoURL = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)).getAttribute("href");
                    urls.add(currentImmoURL);
                    fw.write(currentImmoURL + "\n");
                }
                fw.flush();
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (i > 5) {
                    logger.error("Recurring error, when waiting for results: {}", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        var currentPage = driver.getCurrentUrl();

        click_next: for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                WebElement next = wait
                        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(inputmap.get("Button.Next"))));

                // Scroll the button to the middle of the vieport.
                // Otherwise it can get obstructed by the top or bottom elements
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                        "arguments[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'auto', block: 'center', inline: 'center'});", next);

                next.click();

                var count = 0;

                if (!webDBConfig.checkUrlUnchanged) {
//                 Make sure we actually change page, before we recurse
                    while (currentPage.equals(driver.getCurrentUrl())) {
                        var waitTime = 50;
                        Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                        if (count++ > (20000 / waitTime)) {
                            // We seem to have broken the page. Time to reload
                            logger.warn("Stuck. Hard refreshing the page");
                            driver.get(currentPage);
                            continue click_next;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Thread.sleep(2);
                    List<WebElement> results_after_next = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
                        try {
                            for (WebElement elem : driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"))) {
                                driver.switchTo().frame(elem);
                            }
                            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                            results_after_next = wait.until(presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(inputmap.get("Item.Result"))));
                            break;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (Exception t) {
                                //
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    List<String> urls_new = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int y = 0; y < 30; y++) {
                        try {
                            for (WebElement element : results_after_next) {
                                String currentImmoURL = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)).getAttribute("href");
                                urls_new.add(currentImmoURL);
                            }
                            break;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            if (i > 5) {
                                logger.error("Recurring error, when waiting for results: {}", e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (urls.equals(urls_new)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                iterateResults(driver, wait, inputmap, fw);
                break;
            } catch (TimeoutException | NoSuchElementException e) {
                // This basically only gets thrown, if we are at the last page
                break;
            } catch (ElementClickInterceptedException e) {
                logger.error("Intecepted error: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                // The page changed between finding the button and clicking on it
                // This should never happen, because it leads to bad stuff!
                logger.error("Stale error: " + e.getMessage());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception t) {
                    //
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Unexpected error: " + e.getMessage());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception t) {
                    //
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

